# Array.filter duplicates when returned variable changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

**Note:** I am using react, hence please consider the family array as props.family.

**Issue:**

- Step1: Pass an number argument to getRowData().
- Step2: We will get the result stored in filteredData variable as an array.
- Step3: Now I try to add a new data to filteredData[0] which doesn't exist before.
- Step4: Value of filteredData[0] changes as expected, However the same value is reflected in matching family array aswell.

**Expected:** Change only the filteredData array, family array should never change unless I directly change it.

```
            var family = [{"name":"Jack",  "age": 26},
                          {"name":"Jill",  "age": 22},
                          {"name":"James", "age": 5 },
                          {"name":"Jenny", "age": 2 }];

            const getRowData = age => {
                const tmpval = [...family];
                return tmpval.filter(members => members.age > age);
              };

            const filteredData = getRowData(18);
            //Everything works perfectly till the above line.

            filteredData[0].number = '1';
            console.log(filteredData);
            console.log(family);
            //The number field and value will reflect in both filteredData and family array aswell.
```

Please help me understand better.
The filter function better, filteredData becomes a shallow copy of family array.

Comment: You need to deep clone, not shallow clone, else you're mutating the (single) underlying person object that exists in both arrays

Comment: As the comment suggested by @CertainPerformance you need to deep clone the family object to tempval. const tempval = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(family)) will work perfectly for you.